# how to create own map file with all sub files ,like link node, names, index and etc like following link

Tags: android, graphhopper, mapsforge

I created an offline map for Android. I need to open street map files for my city only. I have `.map` only for my city and `.map` file does not support for find routing.

I need to sub map file for map file like node, names, properties etc. That link contains full country but I need that only for my city.

I am using maps forge for offline map android.

http://folk.ntnu.no/chunf/pocketmaps/maps/

Answer (score 0):

i used this [link](http://extract.bbbike.org/)   for creating .map file 
and create graphhopper routing data with help of crywin terminal.

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.5/docs/core/windows-setup.md

above link is used for routing data